# I'm trying to use a multiple if..else but the commands i put in the cases don't work as intended

Tags: java

So im using the following code but when the time comes for the class to print the tax values they all come out as zero,can anyone tell me why?I have checked and the income values work as intended and are different than zero.

```java
System.out.println("Enter number of clients");
n=scan.nextInt();
int[] income;
income=new int[n];
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<=(n-1);i++){
    System.out.print("Enter income for client no"+(i+1)+":\n");
    int a=scan.nextInt();
    income[i]=a;
}

float tax[ ];      
tax=new float[n];   
for(i=0;i<=(n-1);i++){
    if(income[i]<=0){
        tax[i]=0;
    }else if(income[i]<=10000){
        tax[i]=(income[i]*(9/100));
    }else if(income[i]<=20000){
        tax[i]=income[i]*(22/100);
    }else if(income[i]<=30000){
        tax[i]=income[i]*(28/100);
    }else if(income[i]<=40000){
        tax[i]=income[i]*(36/100);
    }else{
        tax[i]=income[i]*(44/100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use double for fractions. They are being rounded as integers (0)

Comment: Integer division is defined that way.

Comment: Since integers cannot hold fractions, integer division rounds down to the nearest int.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `double` instead of `float` and use this notation when you do the division:

```
tax[i]= income[i] * (9.0 / 100.0);
```